# Can anyone tell me how to get woocommerce thumbnail Url here?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I want get thumbnail image url in the following image attribute

```
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID ); //do this instead
    $end_point   = 'https://api.webpushr.com/v1/notification/send/sid';

    //do a wp_remote_post instead of cURL

    $body = array(
        'title'      => $product->get_name(),
        'message'    => 'check out now',
        'target_url' => $product->get_permalink(),
        'image'      => $product->get_image($attr = array( 'src'=>get_the_post_thumbnail_url())), // Here I want to get Image thumbnail url. But it is not working
        'sid'        => '113858026',
    );
```

Help me finding the problem in array getting image url.

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($product->get_id()), 'single-post-thumbnail' ) this way you can get specific size too if you need

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce post thumbnails and WordPress post thumbnails are the same things. To get the thumbnail URL you can use the below code.

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
```

It will give you the product thumbnail URL.